# Fixing Unbound local error: local variable reference before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error saying "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result_numerator' referenced before assignment" and not sure why. Any kind of help will be appreciated

```
def plus(self, other: "Fraction") -> "Fraction":
    if (self.denominator > other.denominator):
        if (self.denominator / other.denominator).is_integer() == True:
            multiple = self.denominator / other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = other.denominator * multiple
            newSelfNumer = other.numerator * multiple
        else:
            newSelfNumer = self.numerator * other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = self.denominator * other.denominator
            newOtherNumer = other.numerator * self.denominator
            newOtherDenom = other.denominator * self.denominator
    elif (other.denominator > self.denominator):
        if (other.denominator / self.denominator).is_integer() == True:
            multiple = other.denominator / self.denominator
            newOtherDenom = other.denominator * multiple
            newOtherNumer = other.numerator * multiple
        else:
            newSelfNumer = self.numerator * other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = self.denominator * other.denominator
            newOtherNumer = other.numerator * self.denominator
            newOtherDenom = other.denominator * self.denominator
    else:
        result_denominator = self.denominator
        result_numerator = self.numerator + other.numerator
    result = Fraction(result_numerator, result_denominator)
    return result
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbound local variables in a class definition are looked up in the global namespace - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580323/unbound-local-variables-in-a-class-definition-are-looked-up-in-the-global-namesp)

Comment: You are using `result_numerator` outside the scopes where it was defined. Since it's defined inside the `else` block but used outside of it. To make the warning go away declare `result_numerator` before the `if` block.

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference `result_numerator` in the one but last line of your method definition, but it is not defined when `self.denominator <> other denominator`. Better code:

```
def plus(self, other: "Fraction") -> "Fraction":
    if (self.denominator > other.denominator):
        if self.denominator % other.denominator == 0:
            multiple = self.denominator / other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = other.denominator * multiple
            newSelfNumer = other.numerator * multiple
        else:
            newSelfNumer = self.numerator * other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = self.denominator * other.denominator
            newOtherNumer = other.numerator * self.denominator
            newOtherDenom = other.denominator * self.denominator
        result_denominator = newSelfDenom
        result_numerator = newSelfNumer
    elif (other.denominator > self.denominator):
        if other.denominator % self.denominator == 0:
            multiple = other.denominator / self.denominator
            newSelfDenom = other.denominator * multiple
            newSelfNumer = other.numerator * multiple
        else:
            newSelfNumer = self.numerator * other.denominator
            newSelfDenom = self.denominator * other.denominator
            newOtherNumer = other.numerator * self.denominator
            newOtherDenom = other.denominator * self.denominator
        result_denominator = newSelfDenom
        result_numerator = newSelfNumer
    else:
        result_denominator = self.denominator
        result_numerator = self.numerator + other.numerator
    result = Fraction(result_numerator, result_denominator)
    return result
```

Comment: thanks worked but now im getting the same error

Comment: with result_denominator = newSelfDenom, saying that newSelfDenom is referenced before assignment

Comment: Thanks. Fixed in update to answer. The `if` under `elif` didn't follow the pattern of the `if` under the `if`.

Comment: thanks but ran that new code and the result is coming back as none

Comment: most likely because you removed the   result_denominator = self.denominator
 result_numerator = newSelfNumer + self.numerator in the first if but it has to be there though. I tried it with the indentation like how it is in the other if and else but its still not working

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some debugging info, like for example test cases and results, and what you expected?